# Pickle module in Python and text files

Tags: python, text-files, pickle

I have recently asked a question and received an answer that I must 'pickle' my code. As a beginner, I have no idea how to do that.
This was my code:

```
users = []
users.append([username, password])

usersFile = open("users.txt","w+")
for users in users:
  usersFile.write("%s" % users)
usersFile.close()


def loginFunction():
    userEntry = ""

    foundName = 0

    while userEntry == "":
        userEntry = raw_input("Enter your username: ")
        usersFile = open("users.txt", "r")
        lines = usersFile.readlines() 
        for i, user in enumerate(users):
            if userEntry == users[index][0]:
                foundName = 1
                passwordEntry = raw_input("Enter your password: ")
                if passwordEntry == users[index][1]:
                    print "Username and passwords are correct"
                    break
                else:
                    print "incorrect"
                    userEntry = ""
        if foundName == 0:
            print "Username not recognised"
            userEntry = ""
```

My problem was that I was never receiving an "Enter your password" despite knowing that the username I was entering was in fact in the text file in that list. I kept getting "Username not found back" even though I knew it was there. There was mention of not having referred back to lines but again, not sure how I would go about doing that. If someone could help me out by changing up my code and explaining that would be fantastic. I have been referred to documents trying to explain it and have done by own research on the topic but none of it makes sense to me. A written example in this context would help me out a lot.

Comment: This `for users in users:` Looks... problematic. Shouldn't it be `for user in users:` ?

Comment: Are you using linux? If that's so check the permisions you gave to the users.txt file? maybe python can't access to the file and that's the reason of why alway don't get the user.

Comment: @JulioPérez I'm using IDLE Python 2.7.13

Comment: @BorrajaX I have changed it but to no avail. Thank you for your approach though.

Comment: @BorrajaX no problem. Then if it isn't finding the user you are getting "Username not recognised" as output right?

Comment: @JulioPérez i'm digging in the OP's history and the exercise seems to have two parts: One generating a "sample" file with 3 pairs of username/password and the other prompting for a username, verifying if the input string is a valid username (exists in the file) and if it does, prompt for a password. I think the Pickle suggestion that was made here (https://stackoverflow.com/q/48012630/289011) is a tad confusing for the OP. I think a simpler solution would've been easier...

Comment: @BorrajaX  oh ok. Thanks for the explanation bro. Now it makes sense to me because I was checking this post code and realized everything was fine so I didn't comment anymore haha

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, if I understood correctly by looking at the other two questions ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48010959/289011) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48012630/289011)) you made related to this, your problem has two parts:

One is generating a file with a list of user/passwords and the second is using that file to do a "login" system.

The problem with writing to files is that you can regard a file as just text... It doesn't really *retain* the concept of a Python `list` so you need to figure out a way to convert your fancy `users` list of lists to text and then back to a `list` of lists so you can actually use it.

There are many pre-made serializing formats. Here are a few: [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON), [CSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values), [YAML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML), or the one another user recommended in another question, [Pickle](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html)

Since in [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48010959/code-not-working-using-python-tried-converting-from-pseudo-code-to-python-a) you mentioned that you're using this for learning purposes, let's try to keep it as simple as possible ok?

Let's split your exercise in two python files: One to just generate the passwords file and the other that tries to read and verify the username/password that the user entered.

### Script 1: Generate the password file.

So... You have a **`list`** of username/password pairs, and you have to transform that to text so you can store it in a file. Let's just go through each entry in the list and write it to a file. How about using a bit of inspiration from Linux and use the semicolon character (`;`) to mark the separation between username and password on each line of the file? Like this:

```
sample_users = [
    ["user1", "password1"],
    ["user2", "password2"],
    ["user3", "password3"]
]
users_file = open("./users.txt", "w")
for sample_user in sample_users:
    username = sample_user[0]
    password = sample_user[1]
    users_file.write(username + ';' + password + '\n')
users_file.close()
```

Put that in a `.py` file and run it. It should generate a file called `users.txt` right on the same directory where the script is located. I suggest you take a look to the file (any text editor will do). You'll see it looks like this:

```
user1;password1
user2;password2
user3;password3
```

By the way, it's a much better practice taking advantage of the "autoclosing" features provided by Python's [context managers](https://jeffknupp.com/blog/2016/03/07/python-with-context-managers/). You could write that script as:

```
with open("./users.txt", "w") as users_file:
    for sample_user in sample_users:
        username = sample_user[0]
        password = sample_user[1]
        users_file.write(username + ';' + password + '\n')
```

See? No call to `.close()` needed. If something happens while running the code, you will be assured that your file is closed after leaving the `with` block (when the interpreter reaches the end of the `with` block, a call to the File's special function [`__exit__`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1984325/explaining-pythons-enter-and-exit) will be automatically run, and the file will be closed)

---

### Script 2: Use the passwords file

Ok... So we have a file with `username;password\n` on each line. Let's use it.

For this part, you're gonna need to understand what the [`split`](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/dictionary/python-split) (to separate username and password using the semicolon) and [`rstrip`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275018/how-can-i-remove-chomp-a-trailing-newline-in-python) (to remove the newline symbol `\n` at the end) methods of the `str` objects do.

We're gonna need to "rebuild" two variables (`username` and `password`) from a line of text that has the shape `username;password\n`. Then see if the username is found in the file, and if so, prompt the user for the password (and verify it's correct):

```
def loginFunction():
    userEntry = ""
    foundName = False

    while userEntry == "":
        userEntry = raw_input("Enter your username: ")
        usersFile = open("users.txt", "r")
        for line in usersFile:
            print("This is the line I read:%s", line,)
            # Read line by line instead of loading the whole file into memory
            # In this case, it won't matter, but it's a good practice to avoid
            # running out of memory if you have reaaaally large files
            line_without_newline = line.rstrip('\n')       # Remove ending \n
            user_record = line_without_newline.split(';')  # Separate into username and password (make the line a list again)
            userName = user_record[0]
            password = user_record[1]
            # Might as well do userName, password = line_without_newline.split(';')
            if userName == userEntry:
                foundName = True
                print("User found. Verifying password.")
                passwordEntry = raw_input("Enter your password: ")
                if passwordEntry == password:
                    print "Username and passwords are correct"
                    break
                else:
                    print "incorrect"
                    userEntry = ""

        if not foundName:
            print("Username not recognised")
            userEntry = ""


if __name__ == "__main__":
    loginFunction()
```

I believe this should do what you want? Put a comment in the answer if you have other questions.

And have fun coding!

---

**PS: So... How about pickle?**

Pickle is a module that serializes Python objects into files in a "safer" and more automated way. If you wanted to use it, here's how (one way, at least):

1. Generating the passwords file:

   ```
   import pickle

   sample_users = [
       ["user1", "password1"],
       ["user2", "password2"],
       ["user3", "password3"]
    ]

    with open('./users.txt', 'w') as f:
        pickler = pickle.Pickler(f)
        for sample_user in sample_users:
           pickler.dump(sample_user)
   ```

   As before, at this point I would recommend you take a look to how the file `users.txt` looks like with a regular text editor. You'll see it's pretty different to the file before (the one with the username and password separated by semi colons). It's something like this:

   ```
       (lp0
       S'user1'
       p1
       aS'password1'
       p2
       a.(lp3
       S'user2'
       p4
       aS'password2'
       p5
       a.(lp6
       S'user3'
       p7
       aS'password3'
       p8
       a.%
   ```
2. Use the file:

   ```
   import pickle

   def loginFunction():
       userEntry = ""

       while userEntry == "":
           userEntry = raw_input("Enter your username: ")
           usersFile = open("users.txt", "r")
           unpickler = pickle.Unpickler(usersFile)
           while True:
               try:
                   user_record = unpickler.load()
                   userName = user_record[0]
                   password = user_record[1]
                   if userName == userEntry:
                       print("User found. Verifying password.")
                       passwordEntry = raw_input("Enter your password: ")
                       if passwordEntry == password:
                           print "Username and passwords are correct"
                       else:
                           print "incorrect"
                           userEntry = ""
                       # Watch out for the indentation here!!
                       break  # Break anyway if the username has been found


               except EOFError:
                   # Oh oh... the call to `unpickler.load` broke 
                   # because we reached the end of the file and
                   # there's nothing else to load...
                   print("Username not recognised")
                   userEntry = ""
                   break


   if __name__ == "__main__":
       loginFunction()
   ```

If you realize, when you do `user_record = unpickler.load()`, you already get a 2 items Python **`list`** in the `user_record` variable. There's no need for you to transform from text onto list: the `unpickler` has already done that for you. This is possible thanks to of all that "extra" information that was stored by `picker.dump` into the file, which allows the `unpickler` to "know" that the object that needs to be returned is a list.

Comment: Hi. Thank you sooo much for the answer! Its straightforward, easy to understand and exactly what I was looking for! However, I am still receiving the "Username not recognised". I actually realised that it wasn't writing to the file at all with the 'with' function you suggested. Any idea why this might be? I love your style of answering by the way! I might just need you to tutor me haha

Comment: Well... Glad I helped (I like programming, and I guess I like to spread the joy, hehe) As for your question: The `with` is just to "open" the file object and control (or "automate", if you may) its closing. It doesn't really do the writing. The writing is done *within* the `with` block with a file-writing instruction (such as `write`, `writelines`... any of those). Maybe you were missing it? Also, indentation (whitespaces) is important (the `with` opens a new...  block) Is the indentation correct?

Comment: Congratulations!! Since you're using this to learn, I'd recommend putting a lot of `print` statements to see "things" in the code (what the code is doing) Have fun!!

Comment: Great tip thank you! I have learnt a lot from this. Thanks for your help!

Comment: No problem! BTW, I added a final paragraph to my answer (something that was bugging me since I wrote it) to make sure I explained the advantage of using `pickle` (and that is, basically, that pickle/unpickle are capable of knowing what type of object was saved in the file) Enjoy!! **:)**

Answer (score 0):

This is the way you create a login system with pickle however i don't recommend this as there is lot of security issue.I would prefer connecting python to SQL server and storing password in the database.

```
import pickle

def register(username,password):
    user_details = dict()
    with open("users.txt",'rb') as f:
        user_details = pickle.load(f)
    if username in user_details:
        print "User already exsits"
    else:
        user_details[username] = password
        print "User added successfully"
    with open("users.txt",'wb+') as f:
        pickle.dump(user_details,f)

def login(username,password):
    user_details = dict()
    with open("users.txt",'rb') as f:
        user_details = pickle.load(f)
    if username in user_details:
        if user_details[username] == password:
            print "Correct Login successful"
        else:
            print "Incorrect Details"

def init():
    user_details = dict()
    with open("users.txt",'wb+') as f:
        pickle.dump(user_details,f)

init()
register("s","s")
login("s","s")
```

To initialise call the init() function.